# Heroku Site Upload from Different branch

Tags: git, heroku, github

I was working on a team project and my branch is the branch I wanted to upload to heroku. I created the site and my files index.php and composer.json are correct.

I tried to push to heroku from my branch with :

`git push heroku develop-mark`

It responded with:

```
Counting objects: 98, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (90/90), done.
Writing objects: 100% (98/98), 68.22 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 98 (delta 45), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Pushed to non-master branch, skipping build.
To https://git.heroku.com/warm-wave-1067.git
* [new branch]      develop-mark -> develop-mark
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heroku [only builds from its `master` branch](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git#deploying-code), but that doesn't mean that you have to work on `master` locally:

> Branches pushed to Heroku other than `master` will be ignored by this command. If you’re working out of another branch locally, you can either merge to master before pushing, or specify that you want to push your local branch to a remote master. To push a branch other than master, use this syntax:
>
> ```
> $ git push heroku yourbranch:master
> ```

In your case, push your local `develop-mark` branch to Heroku's `master` like so:

```
git push heroku develop-mark:master
```

Comment: `$ git push heroku develop-mark:master
To https://git.heroku.com/warm-wave-1067.git
 ! [rejected]        develop-mark -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/warm-wave-1067.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote
hint: counterpart. Check out this branch and integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g. 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.`

Comment: @MarkA, okay, so your local `develop-mark` branch is behind whatever Heroku is currently running. Either merge that branch into `develop-mark` or rebase `develop-mark` onto that branch, and push again. Or, if you're sure you want to, force push to Heroku. I often force push to development Heroku services.